# Glassfish with Webservices on non default port

Tags: port, glassfish, web-services

I have a simple web service that I created that deploys perfectly on a default Glassfish V2.1 install on both a windows and a linux system.  HOWEVER,  In the production environment, Glassfish has the default port for the domain changed from port 8080 to port 80.  Now when I try to deploy the web service it will not deploy to the server.

The production server is brand new and only was a few webpages on it.  Other than the port everything else seems to be the same.  I cannot change the port on the production server.

In fact I tried to change the port on the linux test server tfrom 8080 to port 80 and I get the same result as the production server.

Any ideas - other than don't use glassfish? :)

Comment: Can you clarify "it will not deploy to the server"? Any errors in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Glassfish as non-root user under Linux?

If so, use root to start Glassfish.

Non-root user can NOT listen on a port under 1024